# How to schedule a task in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web-crawler

I have installed and using WP Crawler Plugin (http://wpcrawler.xyz/guide/#install) for adding posts on my wordpress, it all works fine, but the only thing I would like to do is: How do I make it run every hour or day task run automatically, without me pressing the run button.

I dont see any option plugin having such option, maybe I am missing something or idk.

Comment: `wp cron` would work

Comment: is there any specific plugin for that?

Comment: thnx @hemnathmouli, I thought the plugin itself would have such option but seems it does not... How do u intend to use wp cron with wp crawler I mean how do i connect them, so that the crawler can run automatically

Comment: `https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/` this is the plugin! but you can only add custom cron or schedule with this. You need to write code to integrate both the plugins.

Comment: the wp-crawler seems useless without having it option to auto run tasks... thnx for ur opinions sharing...

Comment: `Tools > Cron Events > Add New` You need to know little programming skill to understand this

Comment: @hemnathmouli I have enought skills of programming, but it just that I have never used Wordpress before....

Comment: @hemnathmouli would appreciate alot some sample or a link that someone else has already done this before!